# Subtract background image from video in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to read first 20 frames from a video, save these images in a folder along with a background image which I obtained by taking median of these 20 images. Then I am trying to subtract this background image from each frame in the video and write the output to a new video. But in the end, I am only getting black output in the new video and getting following warning:
Warning: No video frames were written to this file. The file may be invalid.

> In VideoWriter.VideoWriter>VideoWriter.close at 307
>     In VideoWriter.VideoWriter>VideoWriter.delete at 256
>     In Framextraction at 43

what should I do ?

```
clear all;
clc;
thresh=100;
workingDir = 'D:/DDP/proj3';
mkdir(workingDir)
mkdir(workingDir,'images')
vid= VideoReader('D:/DDP/sample1.3gp');

for k=1:20
img = readFrame(vid);
filename = [sprintf('%01d',k-1) '.jpg'];
imwrite(img,fullfile(workingDir,'images',filename))    
end
folder = 'D:\DDP\proj3\images\';
filelist = dir( fullfile(folder,'*.jpg') );
filelist = strcat(folder, filesep, {filelist.name});

images = zeros(720,1280,3, numel(filelist), 'double');
for i=1:numel(filelist)
images(:,:,:,i) = double( imread(filelist{i}) );
end
background = uint8(median(images, 4)); 
imwrite(background,'D:\DDP\proj3\images\background.jpg','jpg')

fr_size = size(BW1);
width = fr_size(2);
height = fr_size(1);
fg = zeros(height, width);
vid.CurrentTime = 0;  % Rewind video reader
VW = VideoWriter('D:/DDP/proj3/new');
open(VW);
while hasFrame(vid)
fr = readFrame(vid);
fr_diff = abs(double(fr) - double(background));
for j=1:width
for k=1:height
if ((fr_diff(k,j) > thresh))
fg(k,j) = 255;
else
fg(k,j) = 0;
end
end
end
writeVideo(VW,double(fg)/255);

end
close(VW)
cc=  VideoReader('D:/DDP/proj3/new.avi');
cd= VideoWriter('D:/DDP/proj3/new1');
open(cd);
while hasFrame(cc);
    s=readFrame(cc);
    J = imnoise(s,'salt & pepper',0.02);
    img_filtered = J;
    for c = 1 : 3
    img_filtered(:, :, c) = medfilt2(J(:, :, c), [3, 3]);
    end
writeVideo(cd, double(img_filtered)/255);
end
close(cd);
```

Comment: Which line does the error exactly happen?  The line number in your error doesn't correspond to the line number in your code snippet.  There are only 37 lines whereas the line error reported is at line 43.  Please delineate where in the code the error is happening.

Comment: In VW = VideoWriter('D:/DDP/new'); you specified no extension so you will get a Motion JPEG AVI. Double check that CDatas has data and it's in the proper range

Comment: You never return to the beginning of the video. First time you call `hasFrame` it checks for frame 21. Does the video have 21 or more frames?

Comment: Video has 640 frames. but does it matter if it start from 21st frame ? because first 20 frames are equivalent  to background image so their subtraction would give nothing.. Correct me here if I am wrong as I am new in Image Processing

Comment: The background image is double type and frames are int type. So that might be the reason behind it. So how can I convert double to uint ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the error comes from the fact that you did not rewind your video reader to the first frame. The code you posted doesn't seem to correspond to the comment you made regarding the data type of the background image being double type. If you use imread to read background image in, it should be in uint8 type. Here's what I suggest:

```
workingDir = 'D:/DDP';
mkdir(workingDir)
mkdir(workingDir,'images')
vid= VideoReader('D:/DDP/samplee.3gp');

for k=1:20
    img = readFrame(vid);
    filename = [sprintf('%01d',kk-1) '.jpg'];
    imwrite(img,fullfile(workingDir,'images',filename))    
end
folder = 'D:\DDP\images\';
filelist = dir( fullfile(folder,'*.jpg') );
filelist = strcat(folder, filesep, {filelist.name});

images = zeros(720,1280,3, numel(filelist), 'double');
for i=1:numel(filelist)
    images(:,:,:,i) = double( imread(filelist{i}) );
end
background = uint8(median(images, 4)); % Convert background image to uint8 type
imwrite(background,'D:\DDP\images\background.jpg','jpg')

vid.CurrentTime = 0;  % Rewind video reader
VW = VideoWriter('D:/DDP/new');
open(VW);
while hasFrame(vid)
    CDatas(:,:,:) = readFrame(vid) - background;     
    writeVideo(VW,CDatas);   
end
close(VW)
```

Comment: if i convert background image to uint8 type, then it gets black. So the subtraction does no effect and i get the same video as output. Whereas if I don't convert the background to int, then I get the desired background image, but since readFrame(vid) is an uint8 type, error shows while subtracting as i can't subscribe int and double.

Comment: ah. I see. `im2double` turns uint8 image into double type with range between 0 and 1. So when you convert it back to unit8, the image will contain only 0 and 1, which is black or very close to black. Just use `double` to convert the image to double type should work. See edited code.

Comment: Actually i am still getting the blackish subtracted video.  Can you give me your mail id so that i can share video and other details?

Comment: What should i do if i want to subtract each pixel in each frame? I think I should define a threshold value and if difference between pixels value of background and frame is less than that threshold value, then i set that pixel value to zero(i.e black) and 1(otherwise). hence i can get a binary image consisting of  black and white only and I can detect moving person also. What do you think?

Comment: Depending on the content of the image, calculating median value of many images could actually result in something very similar to each image. If you then subtract this from every frame, you would get almost nothing left. Using a threshold value to reject background, of course, is a valid method. You can read this : [graythresh](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html)

Comment: Did something like this, but it is giving error saying " Frames of type double must be in range 0 to 1"

Comment: Did something like this, but it is giving error saying " Frames of type double must be in range 0 to 1" See the edited question for code.

Comment: I was able to get background subtracted video but there occurred some noise in the background. So I used median filter, but it did not help. So can you suggest some way by which I can reduce the noise ? See the question for updated code